# AutoSuggestBox opens up off screen

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp

I have probably the most basic implementation of AutoSuggestBox I can think of.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Grid x:Name="SearchBoxContainer">
        <AutoSuggestBox 
            PlaceholderText="Type a topic name" 
            Margin="8" 
            QueryIcon="Find"  
            DisplayMemberPath="Title" 
            TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
            QuerySubmitted="AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted" 
            SuggestionChosen="AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding MatchingTopics}"
            />
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

When typing in, I get a suggestion list. But it appears ABOVE the autoSuggestBox. The problem is that because I have placed the AutoSuggestBox at the top of the screen already, the suggestion list goes off screen so I can only see one item!

Is it possible to control the direction of the AutoSuggestBox so that it will expand downwards? Why doesn't the AutosuggestBox select the right direction based on available screen real estate?

Comment: It's just a PopUp that does that, you should be able to go set the [PopUp.VerticalOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.verticaloffset.aspx) on it to tell it that if it doesn't have the space it needs from the top of the window that it should pop down instead of up.

Comment: This seems like it should be OOO functionality of the AutoSuggestControl / Popup that it uses. Maybe I am missing something else in my layout?

Comment: Nah you're right, you would expect it. I'd have to see the instance to understand better probably but if you go look at the control template, it's literally just PopUp in there.

Comment: The above XAML is all I am doing. That's why I'm so flabbergasted as how this control could not behave correctly in what I would consider to be a happy path.

Comment: Like Chris W said, your XAML code is right and when I tested with your code, the suggestion list is under the AutoSuggestBox. AutoSuggestBox uses a `Popup` to show the suggestion list. You can find that in [its template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185404.aspx). It can automatically detect where to show the `Popup`. If you remove your `RowDefinitions` and set `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` in AutoSuggestBox, you will see the suggestion list is above the AutoSuggestBox. So I suggest you create a new blank project and only add the AutoSuggestBox to see if it works.

Comment: I had the same issue when running in Debug...
Turns out the AutoSuggestBox acts differently on different screens. My primary (which also happens to be the device screen) drops the suggestion downwards, whilst my two larger, secondary screens open upwards.